# Windows Forms textbox autocompletesource does not work with 'İ' (uppercase) char

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, textbox

I have a function which set autocomplete source an textbox.
When I type **İ** char (turkish uppercase) autocomplete does not work.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you,

My function is below;

```
public static void SetAutoCompleteSource(TextBox box, List<string> values)
        {
            box.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            collection.AddRange(values.ToArray());
            box.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
            box.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this for several diacritics-starting words and all of them worked. Even if I copy your character this works for me. Can you post minimal reproducible example, please?

Comment: I have case sensitive problem. For example in the suggest list i have "Aa","ab","ia","İb". When i type A or a ; Aa and ab appears but when i type "İ" just "İb" appears but "ib" does not appears. Thanks